# rails 4 render partial with other request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to render a js-template without js format and remote true

I have tried this all without success.

```
request.format = :js
render :template => 'tmp.js.erb' 
render :template => 'tmp'
render :template => 'tmp.js.erb', formats: [:js]
```

Do you have any idea, how can I do?

Comment: Can you give us more info? Do you get any error? What is the log printed?

Comment: the partial is renderd but just as html, text

Comment: What happens if you give `render js: 'tmp.js.erb'`

Comment: it is renderd as html

Comment: you can set the default format in route just like match 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :defaults => { :format => 'js' }

Comment: Can you show us the partial code ?

Comment: '$('#modal').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'error') %>");
$('#modal').modal('show')
$('#close_button').focus()
$( "#close_button" ).click(function() {
    $('#js_search').focus()
});'